# Mongodb C# integration with null fields for some record

Tags: c#, mongodb

This is my json file.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"569c6f31f633b10994233f16"},"Name":"jawad","Salary":"1000"}

{"_id":{"$oid":"569c7044f633b126c825e880"},"Name":"noor","Salary":"1000"}

{"_id":{"$oid":"569c97df47c0e25eb3af5928"},"Name":"jawad","Salary":5000.0}

{"_id":{"$oid":"569ca7a9f633b11ba42ffecc"},"Name":"mustaf","Salary":"9000","Telephone":["0700221569","0093799346211"]}

{"_id":{"$oid":"569cb94bf633b12e70eefa10"},"Name":"ramin","Salary":"14000"}

{"_id":{"$oid":"569cb98b617a84b98faf34ca"},"_Id":null,"Name":"ts","Salary":"4444"}

{"_id":{"$oid":"569cba2e617a84b98faf34cb"},"ID":null,"Name":"Dingo","Salary":"90004"}
```

C# code

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String ConnectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    MongoClient MC = new MongoClient(ConnectionString);
    var DB = MC.GetDatabase("test");
    var Col = DB.GetCollection<Result>("Product2");
    var filter=Builders<Result>.Filter.Eq("Name",txtName.Text);
    var Result = Col.Find(filter).SortByDescending(x=>x.Salary).ToList();

    var query = (from r in Col.AsQueryable<Result>().Where<Result>(x => x.Name == txtName.Text).SortBy<Result>("Salary")
                 select new
                  {
                      Id = r._Id,
                      Name = r.Name,
                      Salary = r.Salary,
                      Telephone=r.Telephone
                  }).ToList();

    // count of total records.

    int TotalElements = query.Count();
    lblTotal.Text = TotalElements.ToString();

    gvResult.DataSource = query;
    gvResult.DataBind();
}



public class Result
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    [BsonElement]
    public List<String> Telephone { get; set; }

}
```

Aspx file

```
<div class="Body">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td><td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Salary</td><td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSalary" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblID"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button Text="Save" runat="server" ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                    <asp:Button Text="Search" runat="server" ID="btnSearch" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>



    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvResult">

    </asp:GridView>

    <div class="CountDiv">
    <span>Total Elements:</span><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotal"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have 1 telephone field for one record but not for the rest how can I make the query to scape null telephone I get error:

> No matching creator found.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nFBb.jpg)

Comment: did you tried in your where clause to filter out null values.?

Comment: thanks rummykhan ,  i need to bind it to gridview and need to display telephone field in gridview and display null for records that do not have telephone , this will not bring the records which does not have telephone if i add this in where clause. .Where<Result>(x => x.Name == txtName.Text && x.Telephone.Count > 0)

Comment: Does this solve ur issue.. and what about x.Telephone == null

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from r in Col.AsQueryable<Result>()
                       .Where<Result>(x => x.Name == txtName.Text && x.Telephone.Count > 0)
                       .SortBy<Result>("Salary")
                       select new
                       {
                          Id = r._Id,
                          Name = r.Name,
                          Salary = r.Salary,
                          Telephone=r.Telephone
                       }
             ).ToList();
```

Glad it solved ur issue.

Comment: this will not bring the field name="jawad" which does not have telephone field. can we use or ?